# How to check date-time of remote servers?

Tags: windows

Actually i have a list of 150 server IP where one of that servers have a wrong date-time set, is there  a way to check from my PC the date-time of all of them?

like by pinging or something like that the servers..

Comment: Great that you were able to solve this. But please don't edit your solution into your question. Post it as an answer and accept it, so the question is marked as "solved" in the system. Otherwise it will pop up over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using the following foreach and net time

```
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("\Desktop\we.txt"))
{ 
       net time \\$line
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With PowerShell you can run commands on the remote computer:

```powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputer -ScriptBlock { get-date; }
```

This will output the date and time on RemoteComputer.

If your servers are in an ActiveDirectory you can get the names from there and loop over them:

```powershell
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Foreach-Object { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_.name -ScriptBlock { get-date; } }
```

This will return all computers in AD. You can filter them as you need.

Of course you can use anything as a source for the servers. Text file, csv, everything PowerShell can read and/or import.